# Python comprehension with multiple prints

Tags: python, printing, list-comprehension, set-comprehension

I want to put this for loop into a comprehension. Is this even possible?

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    result = len({tuple(walk) for (walk, distance) in dic[i] if distance == 0})
    print(f'There are {result} different unique walks with length {i}')
```

I tried stuff like

```
print({tuple(walk) for i in range(1, 11)  for (walk, distance) in dic[i] if distance == 0})
```

but this prints all walks for all i together, but i want 10 different print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close actually:

```
[print(f'There are {len({tuple(walk) for (walk, distance) in dic[i] if distance == 0})} different unique walks with length {i}') for i in range(1,11)]
```

But it's a long and ugly oneliner, in a regular `for` loop it looks way better.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but I'd not recommend doing that. You can actually use a list comprehension for that but it would really defy their purpose.

You can use functions in comprehensions, but usually their return values is accumulated in the structure. Since the `print` function doesn't return a value (`None`), such a comprehension would accumulate a series of `None`s, which is not very pythonic.

```py
>>> res = [print(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
1
2
...
>>> res
[None, None, ...]
```

Much better is to collect all the lines you want to print and concatenate them together (for example using `str.join` or unpacking them into `print`):

```py
>>> print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 11)))
1
2
...
```

**or**

```py
>>> res = [i for i in range(1, 11)]
>>> res
[1, 2, ...]
>>> print(*res, sep='\n')
1
2
...
```